# Android Studio generates three separate apps after I compiled and ran in the android emulator

Tags: java, android

I have upgraded my Android studio. 
I think there is something different from the previous version
When I finished writing the code and compile then run. I look something different like this:

[image]

Whether it's something new or I destructive my android studio settings

Comment: Please provide the contents of `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: OK thanks.. My error is in the AndroidManifest.. Forgive me for my folly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because you have posted below code in three different activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

the mistake you have done is like below in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity
     android:name=".SplashActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
     android:name=".HomeActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: OK thanks.. My error is in the AndroidManifest.. Forgive me for my folly

Answer (score 1):

May be you create multiple intent-filter in android AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: OK thanks.. My error is in the AndroidManifest.. Forgive me for my folly